# convert the values from the json to drop down

Tags: php, json, forms, decode

i would like to extract all the values that correspond to the organisations to come under the drop down menu as options for organisation,but now only the last value of the oraganisation is showing up in the drop down as an option
here is my code

```
<?php
$items = json_decode('[{"location":[{"building":   ["Building1"],"name":"Location1"}],"name":"Organization1"},{"location":[{"building":["Building2"],"name":"location2"}],"name":"Organisation2"},{"location":[{"building":["Building3"],"name":"Location3"}],"name":"Organization3"}]');
foreach( $items as $each ){
echo $each->location[0]->building[0];
echo $each->location[0]->name;
echo $each->name;
}
$org=$each->name;
$arr=array($org);
reset($arr);
//print_r($org); 
//$result = count($org);
//echo $result;
while(list(,$value)=each($arr)){
//echo "value:$value<br/>\n";
//$_SESSION['organisation']=$value;
//echo $_SESSION['organisation'];

}?>
<select name="category_id">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$count1=count($keys);
echo $count1;
for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++)
{?>
<option value="<?php echo $keys[$i]; ?>"><?php echo $arr[$i]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
<?php
$org = array();
$items = json_decode('[{"location":[{"building":   ["Building1"],"name":"Location1"}],"name":"Organization1"},{"location":[{"building":["Building2"],"name":"location2"}],"name":"Organisation2"},{"location":[{"building":["Building3"],"name":"Location3"}],"name":"Organization3"}]');
foreach( $items as $each ){
$org[]=$each->name;
}
?>
<select name="category_id">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
foreach($org as $key=>$val)
{?>
<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $val; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: @user2201395 Glad it helped..:). But you can only accept any 1 answer not both..:D

Comment: also see for location as well

Answer (score 1):

Make use of that first foreach rather than starting an entire new loop. Tested and this works:

```
<?php
    $items = json_decode('[{"location":[{"building":   ["Building1"],"name":"Location1"}],"name":"Organization1"},{"location":[{"building":["Building2"],"name":"location2"}],"name":"Organisation2"},{"location":[{"building":["Building3"],"name":"Location3"}],"name":"Organization3"}]');
    echo '<select name="category_id"><option value=""></option>';
    $stepper = 0;
    foreach($items as $each) {
        $building = $each->location[0]->building[0];
        $name = $each->location[0]->name;
        $final_name = $each->name;
        echo '<option value="'.$stepper.'">'.$final_name.'</option>';
        $stepper++;
    }
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: @Yogesh how can i bring the drop down for both buildings and locations.Thank you